# Is it possible to use Vapor web framework with Swift 2.2?

Tags: swift, vapor

How can I install Vapor on Ubuntu 14, and install it locally to use the latest Swift release?

Comment: Dude you can find everything here https://github.com/qutheory/vapor. Just read their readme...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

The latest Vapor (**v0.14**) only support Swift 3.0. You can visit the docs for instructions on how to install:

http://docs.qutheory.io

For Vapor **v0.3** and prior:

Yes, Vapor officially supports Swift 2.2 and Swift 3.0.

To install on Linux, paste the following commands into your terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/qutheory/vapor
cd vapor
git checkout swift-2-2
sudo make install
```

After you do that, you will have access to the `vapor` command line interface.

Run `vapor help` to see the available commands.

Visit [Getting Started](https://github.com/qutheory/vapor/wiki/Setup) in the Vapor Wiki to learn more about installing Vapor.

Comment: It's currently pretty unclear from the docs how to get started with Swift 2.2. `vapor new <name>` is only applicable to Swift 3. And there's no sample project to clone for Swift 2.2 (or at least it's unclear what to clone).

Comment: @bobics There is a branch dedicated to Swift 2.2 support. https://github.com/qutheory/vapor/tree/swift-2-2